# Change adapter from static IP to DHCP

Tags: powershell, dhcp, group-policy

I want to change the interfaces of all computers of two AD OUs. Currently all interfaces have static IPs and DNS servers. I wrote this Powershell Script:

```
$getIP = get-netipaddress | Where-Object IPAddress -Like "192.168.18.*"
$index = $getip.InterfaceIndex
Get-NetIPInterface | where-Object InterfaceIndex -like "$index" | Set-NetIPInterface -Dhcp Enabled
$rep = Get-NetIPInterface | where-Object InterfaceIndex -like "$index"
$rep1 = $rep.InterfaceAlias
$Hostn = hostname
$Test = Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $index | Where-Object {$_.Dhcp -like "Enabled"}
if ($Test){
$DHCPSTATUS = "DHCP active"
$report = "The Interface $Rep1 on $Hostn was set to DHCP . The DNS Server are resettet"
Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex "$index" -ResetServerAddresses
}
else{
$DHCPSTATUS = "DHCP_not_active"
$report = "The Interface $Rep1 on $Hostn was NOT set to DHCP . The DNS Server are NOT resettet"
}
$report | Out-File \\Server\d$\DHCP\Result\$Hostn"_"$DHCPSTATUS.txt
```

For the two OUs I enabled a GPO with a Startscript:
[Link to Image of OU][1]

When I run gpresult, It shows that the GPO was used, but nothing happened to the interface, neither was a txt written.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSZbV.png

Comment: Do the computers have permission to read/execute the script?

Comment: From my understanding if the script is run via GPO it's the system that's running it. I also did a similar thing for changing the the DNS Servers for all of our 1000 clients which worked fine. Also a PS srcipt via GPO, everything set up the same way. That's why I think it might be something wrong with the script.

Comment: The machine accounts need read/execute permissions for the script. It's likely not the issue if it's working with other scripts but worth checking if this script is in a different location.

Answer (score 0):

Try using batch instead of PowerShell with the
[netsh command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-contexts):

```
netsh interface ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /registerdns
```

Comment: thx i'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to replace all my old scripts with updated scripts that utilize PowerShell 5.1 and standard cmdlets, and ended up with this:

```
## Get the Physical NIC
$adapter = Get-NetAdapter -Physical

## Get the NIC Name as a System Variable
$nicName = $Adapter.Name

## Get the NIC Index
$nicIndex = $adapter.ifIndex

## Set the network interface to a variable for future use
$interface = Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $nicIndex -AddressFamily IPv4

## Remove the static default gateway
Remove-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $nicIndex -AddressFamily IPv4 -Confirm:$false

## Set interface to "Obtain an IP address automatically"
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceIndex $nicIndex -Dhcp Enabled

## Set interface to "Obtain DNS server address automatically"
$interface | Set-DnsClientServerAddress -ResetServerAddresses

## Sleep to allow some environments to process (older hardware)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

## Restart the NIC for Sanity
Restart-NetAdapter -Name $nicName -Confirm:$false -Verbose

## Sleep to allow some environments to process (older hardware)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10

## Display new IP 
### (nice for me as I utilize this information but not needed)
$NewIP = (Get-NetIPAddress -InterfaceIndex $nicIndex).IPv4Address
$NewIP

## Register the adapter in DNS
Register-DnsClient -Verbose

## Flush the DNS cache
Clear-DnsClientCache -Verbose
```